# how to generate presigned url of files in protected folder using AWS Amplify

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-amplify

we have a react application build using AWS Amplify and use cognito user pool to manage the user authentication.
The admin user can create a product and then a normal user can view that product and purchase it. Basically its kind of shopping cart site.
The products are saved using -

```
DataStore.save(
 new Products(productDetails)
);
```

and some images are also uploaded to S3 bucket in protected level -

```
Storage.put(File.key, File.file, {
 level: 'protected',
 contentType: File.file.type
});
```

now how should the presigned url be generated for these protected files, as it requires the identityId, and how do we know which admin user uploaded this file -

```
Storage.get(File.key, { 
    level: 'protected'
    identityId: 'xxxxxxx'
});
```